# findContours in opencv with "System.AccessViolationException"

Tags: opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use the findContours function in Opencv2.4.4 with VS2010express(C++) the code is below.
    Mat canny_output;
    std::vector > contours;

```
/// Detect edges using canny
Canny( src_gray, canny_output, 100, 200, 3 );
/// Find contours
threshold(canny_output,canny_output,0,255,THRESH_BINARY);

findContours( canny_output, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

but the program will always trigger breakpoint at the last line with the system error System.AccessViolationException.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. make sure `contours` is `vector< vector<Point> >`
2. After a Canny operation you can directly feed the edges to findContour..why are you doing a thresholding? that too with a threshold value of zero...skip that line...because the output of canny is a binary image.
3. Make sure `cannny_output` is also a gray image.

EDIT: try this ..although this gives external contours..check wether findcontour is orking or not..

`findContours(canny_output,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,Point())`

Comment: I already define the contours as vector< vector<Point> >, after I delete the threshold line, the error become "the heap was destroyed",any more ideas?

Comment: comment out findContours and try imshow("CANNY",canny_output)...check the image after edge detection.

Comment: the image after canny can be normally output, but it crashed at the findContours

Comment: the one with a point doesn't work. I looked into the findContours function and find that the following will cause crash: _contours.create(total, 1, 0, -1, true);